# UIView animation not working with addSubview

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiviewanimation

I have an iPad app that is displaying a "note" (subclassed `UILabel`) with text on it. In order to navigate to the next note, I'd like it to slide it off the screen to the left while having the next one slide in from the right. I can get either animation to work, but not both at the same time.

Here's the code in my controller:

```
- (void)slideOutLeft {
    // create the new note
    flSlidingNote *newNote = [[flSlidingNote alloc] init];
    newNote.text = @"blah blah";
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(1000, 70, 637, 297); // off the right
    newNote.frame = newFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:newNote];

    // slide off the current one
    CGRect currentFrameEnd = noteLabel.frame; // noteLabel is the existing note
    currentFrameEnd.origin.x = 0 - noteLabel.frame.size.width; // off the left

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        noteLabel.frame = currentFrameEnd;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

`noteLabel` does not animate at all. If I comment out the `addSubview:newNote` part it does. I'm still relatively new at this, so it's probably just something simple.

The problem happens whether `newNote` is animated or not (not animated in the code snippet).

Comment: I'm taking a look at it, in the meanwhile let me say that starting a class name with a lowercase letter it's a very bad practice.

Comment: Yeah, it's an artifact from when I was first learning stuff. I'll fix it eventually.

Comment: I took a look and I've exactly your same issue. It's probably due to concurrent manipulations of two different subview. You may want to user a `CAAnimationGroup` which according to the doc `allows multiple animations to be grouped and run concurrently.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put the animation for *both* your views and the addSubview call for your new view in one animation block, like so:

```
  // layout the new label like the old, but 300px offscreen right 
  UILabel * newNote = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectOffset(self.noteLabelView.frame, 300, 0)];
  newNote.text = @"NEW NOTE";

 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
                       delay:0
                     options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                  animations:^{
                     // animate the old label left 300px to offscreen left
                     self.noteLabelView.center = CGPointMake(self.noteLabelView.center.x-300, self.noteLabelView.center.y);
                     // add the new label to the view hierarchy
                     [self.view addSubview:newNote];
                     // animate the new label left 300px into the old one's spot
                    newNote.center = CGPointMake(newNote.center.x-300, newNote.center.y);
                  }
                  completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    // remove the old label from the view hierarchy
                    [self.noteLabelView removeFromSuperview];
                    // set the property to point to the new label
                    self.noteLabelView = newNote;
               }];
```

In this snippet above, I'm assuming the old label is addressable via the property `self.noteLabelView`.

(Also have a look at https://github.com/algal/SlidingNotes , though I can't promise that will stay there long so maybe SO isn't the right format for such a link? )

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work :-(, does the same thing: noteLabelView stays put and newNote slides in (I created a brand new project to try it out in too). I will take a look at the github project though.

Comment: Just downloaded and ran your sample. Does it matter that I am *not* using Storyboards? And I'm running an iPad app too.

Comment: Storyboard is fine, as long as you're not using auto layout. You said this snippet doesn't work: so did the sample app not work?

Comment: The app did work. In my iPad app, I *am* using autolayout, which sounds like it might be the culprit. What's the workaround for that?

Comment: If you're using auto layout, and setting up constraints manually or via IB (rather than using translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints), then you should not be calling setFrame: anywhere in your code. The point of auto layout is that you only configure constraints, and then auto layout automatically lays out the frame. So you need to specify your animation by tweaking constraints and calling layoutIfNeeded. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461347/uiimages-move-to-the-center-when-going-to-another-view/13542306#13542306

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what Gabriele Petronella commented, here is a good resource on KeyFrames and AnimationGroup, with a sample GitHub project linked:

http://blog.corywiles.com/using-caanimationgroup-for-view-animations

This really helped me understand animations better.

Answer (score -1):

not sure but i've seen other code that loops through subviews and performs animations, you may want to try the following:

```
for(UIView *view in self.subviews)
{
    // perform animations 
}
```

Comment: You should add a brief description of why this might work to improve your answer.